# bootstrap 4 dropdown disappears behind div in tables system system

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

In the first place, it is a dynamic table made with divs, in turn,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aL6w.png) it can be scrolled horizontally, and also each row of the table has a collapse to display other rows within its step two images so you can see.. I need the dropdown like a z-index 9999, that is, above all the elements inclusive of the table, but I cannot make it floating, why each drop-down menu must go below the action button, the three points.

these 3 elements are requirements, 1.- the horizontal displacement through the table can have N number of columns, 2.- the actions button (the 3 points) must be fixed to the right so that with all the horizontal displacement it remains visible and 3.- the collapse in each element of the table, because each workflow has stages and related activities.

https://www.codeply.com/p/WdmSpQTJcr here is the example no copy the styles but the functionality is alright

[first capture it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aL6w.png)
[second capture it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8oZt.png)

```css
:root {
  --colorTextoClaro: #999999;
  --colorTexto: #373838;
  --colorTextoOscuro: #5B5B5B;
  --verdePrincipal: #009A3C;
  --fondoGrisClaro: #F5F4F4;
  --fondoSwt: #FCFCFC;
  --bordeInputs: #C4C4C4;
  --naranjaLogo: #F19B0A;
  --naranjaStatus: #F39200;
  --rojoStatus: #da251c;
  --grisFooter: #6D777A;
  --hrColor: #E0E0E0;
  --grisSexto: #8A8C8E;
  --bgComentarios: #FAFAFA;
  --colorDateCommet: #CFCECE;
  --myselfMsg: #CAFFAA;
  --verdeStatusBar: #4FB725;
  --verdeSubMenu: rgba(3, 137, 58, 0.98);
  --hoverRows: #e0f1e7;
  --verdeActive: #019A40;
  --fondoToolTip: #FFFDFD;
  --borderToolTip: #EAEAEA;
}

a {
  color: var(--verdePrincipal);
}

body {
  color: var(--colorTexto);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
}

a:hover {
 color: var(--verdePrincipal) !important;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.wm-100 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.mb-18 {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.m-75 {
  padding-left: 75px !important;
}
.sp {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.sm {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.row_wfl_ppal {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar {
      height: 5px;
      margin: 0px 10px;
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      background-color: #F5F5F5;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: #b3b3b3;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -4px;
      vertical-align: top;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column:first-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column:last-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.ic_ddwn,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column:first-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column.ic_ddwn,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column:first-child,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column.ic_ddwn {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 4%;
      flex: 0 0 4%;
      max-width: 4%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead {
      height: 76px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column {
      border-bottom: 2px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
      color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 21px;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
      height: 75px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .intern_clp_link,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .intern_clp_link {
      color: var(--verdePrincipal);
      position: absolute;
      left: -45px;
      top: 24px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .intern_clp_link span,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .intern_clp_link span {
      font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item .sort {
      color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 21px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item .sort:hover span {
      color: var(--verdePrincipal);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_colmumn_name,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_colmumn_name,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_colmumn_name,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_colmumn_name {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 23.2%;
      flex: 0 0 23.2%;
      max-width: 23.2%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_colmumn_type,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_colmumn_type,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_colmumn_type,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_colmumn_type {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 10.5%;
      flex: 0 0 10.5%;
      max-width: 10.5%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column .item {
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: normal;
      word-break: break-word;
      display: flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column .item {
      opacity: .75;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed .item {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .sort span {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 2px;
      color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .icon_box {
      background-color: var(--verdePrincipal);
      border-radius: 22px;
      height: 22px;
      width: 22px;
      display: flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .icon_box span {
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody.filaAbierta {
      position: relative;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody.filaAbierta .item_column {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .second_table {
      position: relative;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .second_table:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 74px;
      height: 1px;
      background-color: var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table {
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(2),
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(3) {
      padding-left: 43px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column:nth-child(2) .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column:nth-child(3) .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(2) .item,
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(3) .item {
      justify-content: flex-start;
      -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .resp_photo {
      display: block;
      margin: 0px 0px 8px;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .resp_photo img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-height: 33px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .info_respo {
      color: #999999;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 12px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 14px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.btn_action_fixed a [class^="icon-"],
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.btn_action_fixed a [class*=" icon-"] {
      font-size: 1em;
      margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .responsable {
      flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .status {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      margin-right: 6px;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .cerrado {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: white;
      border-top-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-bottom-color: white;
      border-left-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .cerrado:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--verdeStatusBar);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .pendiente {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: --colorTextoClaro;
      border-top-color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      border-bottom-color: --colorTextoClaro;
      border-left-color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .pendiente:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--colorTextoClaro);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .rechazado {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-top-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-bottom-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-left-color: var(--rojoStatus);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .rechazado:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--rojoStatus);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .finalizado {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-top-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-bottom-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-left-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .finalizado:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--verdeStatusBar);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .en_proceso {
      border-radius: 12px;
      border-right-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-top-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-bottom-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-left-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
      border-width: 8px;
      border-style: solid;
      height: 0px;
      margin-right: 6px;
      position: relative;
      width: 0px;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .en_proceso:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: 0px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid var(--naranjaStatus);
      margin: auto;
      border-radius: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .active {
      color: var(--verdePrincipal);
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .dropdown-menu {
      right: 0px;
      transform: none !important;
      will-change: initial !important;
      top: 45px !important;
      left: auto !important;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table {
      position: relative
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: white;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .btn_action_fixed,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed {
      background-color: white;
      right: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 4%;
      flex: 0 0 4%;
      max-width: 4%;
      opacity: 1;
      position: sticky;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: -moz-sticky;
      position: -o-sticky;
      position: -ms-sticky;
  }
  .row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span,
  .row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span,
  .row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span {
      margin-right: 16px !important;
  }

  .icon_box {
    color: white;
  }

  .icon_box:hover {
    color: white !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid sp" style="min-width: 1440px;">
    <div class="row sm flex-nowrap flex-column row_wfl_ppal">
        <div class="ppal_table div_thead">
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" class="sort" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="icon-icon_arrow-down2"></span> Código
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ascendente</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Descendente</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" class="sort" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="icon-icon_arrow-down2"></span> Nombre del workflow
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ascendente</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Descendente</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Tracking</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Tracking</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Fecha de inicio</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Fecha de fin</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">Estado</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column">
                <div class="item">Responsable</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                <div class="item">Tipo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTableAddColumn">
                        +
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ppal_table div_tbody">
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <a class="icon_box collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="submenu1">
                        >
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">WF0025</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                <div class="item">Procedimiento horas extras</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">25/03/2020</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">10/01/2020</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column">
                <div class="item">
                    <span class="status cerrado"></span> Cerrado
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 item_column">
                <div class="item responsable">
                    <figure class="resp_photo"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0Pca271LUiEyu-Np7IYtmgUm5MEhYutLik4loBfq0wwap4Uxo&s" alt="user1" class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></figure>
                    <p class="mb-0 info_respo">Ayer a las 3:20 pm</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                <div class="item">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        ...
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                            <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="break"></div>
            <div class="second_table w-100 collapse" id="submenu1">
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                    <div class="item">
                        <a class="intern_clp_link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#thirdMenu1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdMenu1">
                            >
                        </a>
                        Etapa 1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card4
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card5
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card6
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card7
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 item_column">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card8
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                    <div class="item">
                        Card9
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
                    <div class="item">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            ...
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                                <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="third_table w-100 collapse multi-collapse" id="thirdMenu1">
                    <div class="col-1 item_column"> 
                        <div class="item">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column"> 
                        <div class="item">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card4
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card5
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card6
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card7
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 item_column">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card7
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
                        <div class="item">
                            Card8
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                ...
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                                    <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first problem, the dropdown menu just shows half because it overflows the parent container. If you want the overflow content to be shown correctly, the overflow property needs to be set to visible. I tried to remove the overflow-x and overflow-y (default property is visible) of class `.row_wfl_ppal` and the dropdown menu displays correctly. However, the last two columns are overflow and displayed out of the container. If we set overflow-x to auto and overflow-y to visible, the overflow-y property will automatically set to auto.

Answer (score 0):

I am only able to fix one of your problems. The drop-down menu goes above the action button, the three points.

The code change is to remove the `position` **sticky** from `... .btn_action_fixed {}`.

```css
:root {
  --colorTextoClaro: #999999;
  --colorTexto: #373838;
  --colorTextoOscuro: #5B5B5B;
  --verdePrincipal: #009A3C;
  --fondoGrisClaro: #F5F4F4;
  --fondoSwt: #FCFCFC;
  --bordeInputs: #C4C4C4;
  --naranjaLogo: #F19B0A;
  --naranjaStatus: #F39200;
  --rojoStatus: #da251c;
  --grisFooter: #6D777A;
  --hrColor: #E0E0E0;
  --grisSexto: #8A8C8E;
  --bgComentarios: #FAFAFA;
  --colorDateCommet: #CFCECE;
  --myselfMsg: #CAFFAA;
  --verdeStatusBar: #4FB725;
  --verdeSubMenu: rgba(3, 137, 58, 0.98);
  --hoverRows: #e0f1e7;
  --verdeActive: #019A40;
  --fondoToolTip: #FFFDFD;
  --borderToolTip: #EAEAEA;
}

a {
  color: var(--verdePrincipal);
}

body {
  color: var(--colorTexto);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--verdePrincipal) !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.wm-100 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.mb-18 {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.m-75 {
  padding-left: 75px !important;
}

.sp {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.sm {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.row_wfl_ppal {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 5px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.row_wfl_ppal::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column:first-child,
.row_wfl_ppal .ppal_table .item_column:last-child,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.ic_ddwn,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column:first-child,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column.ic_ddwn,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column:first-child,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column.ic_ddwn {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 4%;
  flex: 0 0 4%;
  max-width: 4%;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead {
  height: 76px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column {
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--hrColor);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
  color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
  height: 100%;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column {
  height: 75px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .intern_clp_link,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .intern_clp_link {
  color: var(--verdePrincipal);
  position: absolute;
  left: -45px;
  top: 24px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .intern_clp_link span,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .intern_clp_link span {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item .sort {
  color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item .sort:hover span {
  color: var(--verdePrincipal);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_colmumn_name,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_colmumn_name,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_colmumn_name,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_colmumn_name {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 23.2%;
  flex: 0 0 23.2%;
  max-width: 23.2%;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_colmumn_type,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_colmumn_type,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_colmumn_type,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_colmumn_type {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 10.5%;
  flex: 0 0 10.5%;
  max-width: 10.5%;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column .item {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .item_column .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .item_column .item {
  opacity: .75;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed .item {
  opacity: 1;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column .sort span {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .icon_box {
  background-color: var(--verdePrincipal);
  border-radius: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .icon_box span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody.filaAbierta {
  position: relative;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody.filaAbierta .item_column {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .second_table {
  position: relative;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .second_table:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 74px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: var(--hrColor);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .third_table {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--hrColor);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .third_table:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(2),
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 43px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column:nth-child(2) .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_thead .item_column:nth-child(3) .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(2) .item,
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column:nth-child(3) .item {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .resp_photo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px 0px 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .resp_photo img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 33px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .info_respo {
  color: #999999;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.btn_action_fixed a [class^="icon-"],
.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column.btn_action_fixed a [class*=" icon-"] {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .responsable {
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .status {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .cerrado {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-right-color: white;
  border-top-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-left-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .cerrado:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--verdeStatusBar);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .pendiente {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-right-color: --colorTextoClaro;
  border-top-color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
  border-bottom-color: --colorTextoClaro;
  border-left-color: var(--colorTextoClaro);
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .pendiente:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--colorTextoClaro);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .rechazado {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-right-color: var(--rojoStatus);
  border-top-color: var(--rojoStatus);
  border-bottom-color: var(--rojoStatus);
  border-left-color: var(--rojoStatus);
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .rechazado:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--rojoStatus);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .finalizado {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-right-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
  border-top-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
  border-bottom-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
  border-left-color: var(--verdeStatusBar);
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .finalizado:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--verdeStatusBar);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .en_proceso {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-right-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
  border-top-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
  border-bottom-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
  border-left-color: var(--naranjaStatus);
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 0px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .en_proceso:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--naranjaStatus);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .active {
  color: var(--verdePrincipal);
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .item_column .item .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0px;
  transform: none !important;
  will-change: initial !important;
  top: 45px !important;
  left: auto !important;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table {
  position: relative
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .btn_action_fixed,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed {
  background-color: white;
  right: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 4%;
  flex: 0 0 4%;
  max-width: 4%;
  opacity: 1;
  /*
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  */
}

.row_wfl_ppal .div_tbody .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span,
.row_wfl_ppal .second_table .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span,
.row_wfl_ppal .third_table .btn_action_fixed .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item span {
  margin-right: 16px !important;
}

.icon_box {
  color: white;
}

.icon_box:hover {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid sp" style="min-width: 1440px;">
  <div class="row sm flex-nowrap flex-column row_wfl_ppal">
    <div class="ppal_table div_thead">
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="sort" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="icon-icon_arrow-down2"></span> Código
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ascendente</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Descendente</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" class="sort" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="icon-icon_arrow-down2"></span> Nombre del workflow
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ascendente</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Descendente</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">Tracking</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">Tracking</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">Fecha de inicio</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">Fecha de fin</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">Estado</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 item_column">
        <div class="item">Responsable</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
        <div class="item">Tipo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalTableAddColumn">
                        +
                    </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ppal_table div_tbody">
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">
          <a class="icon_box collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="submenu1">
                        >
                    </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">WF0025</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
        <div class="item">Procedimiento horas extras</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">25/03/2020</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">10/01/2020</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column">
        <div class="item">
          <span class="status cerrado"></span> Cerrado
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 item_column">
        <div class="item responsable">
          <figure class="resp_photo"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS0Pca271LUiEyu-Np7IYtmgUm5MEhYutLik4loBfq0wwap4Uxo&s" alt="user1" class="img-fluid rounded-circle"></figure>
          <p class="mb-0 info_respo">Ayer a las 3:20 pm</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
        <div class="item">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
        <div class="item">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        ...
                    </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
              <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
              <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="break"></div>
      <div class="second_table w-100 collapse" id="submenu1">
        <div class="col-1 item_column">
          <div class="item">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column">
          <div class="item">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
          <div class="item">
            <a class="intern_clp_link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#thirdMenu1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="thirdMenu1">
                            >
                        </a> Etapa 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column">
          <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column">
          <div class="item">
            Card4
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column">
          <div class="item">
            Card5
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column">
          <div class="item">
            Card6
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column">
          <div class="item">
            Card7
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 item_column">
          <div class="item">
            Card8
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
          <div class="item">
            Card9
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            ...
                        </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_table w-100 collapse multi-collapse" id="thirdMenu1">
          <div class="col-1 item_column">
            <div class="item">
              &nbsp;
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column">
            <div class="item">
              &nbsp;
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 item_column item_colmumn_name">
            <div class="item">
              Card3
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column">
            <div class="item">0 de 2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column">
            <div class="item">
              Card4
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column">
            <div class="item">
              Card5
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column">
            <div class="item">
              Card6
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column">
            <div class="item">
              Card7
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 item_column">
            <div class="item">
              Card7
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column item_colmumn_type">
            <div class="item">
              Card8
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 item_column btn_action_fixed ic_ddwn">
            <div class="item">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                ...
                            </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarWorkflow">
                  <span class="icon-icon_pencil"></span> Editar
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <span class="icon-icon_trash-light"></span> Eliminar
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave here a working suggestion on bootstrap 4.6 (write classes: `dropdown position-static`) tried from [Bootstrap dropdown partially hidden by table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476213/bootstrap-dropdown-partially-hidden-by-table-cells).